# Category of (co)commutative Hopf monoids

Tags: category-theory, abelian-categories, hopf-algebras

Let $(C, \otimes)$ be an exact monoidal category, and let $H(C)$ be the category of cocommutative and commutative Hopf monoids in $C$ with respect to $\otimes$.

What can be said about this category? Is it always abelian? If so, are there always enough projectives or injectives? I know that if $C$ is the category of vector spaces over some field with the standard tensor, then $H(C)$ is abelian. Can this be generalized?

Comment: In order to specify what "commutative and cocommutative Hopf monoid" means you need to pick a symmetric monoidal structure on $C$; in the case of vector spaces this is the tensor product, so it doesn't come for free just from being an exact category. If you pick the cartesian product then every object has a unique cocommutative comonoid structure (exercise) and so it turns out that you are just asking about abelian groups in $C$.

Comment: Ah yes thank you, the question has been edited. I'm not just thinking about the Cartesian product, it could be some other tensor

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/45429/the-category-of-abelian-group-objects asserts that the category of abelian group objects in an exact category is exact. Commutative and cocommutative Hopf monoids are abelian group objects in cocommutative comonoids, so if you can prove that that category is abelian then you're done. I don't know what hypotheses are needed for this.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan That seems much stronger than necessary, at least a priori. Do you think I should post this question on MO?

Comment: Seems sensible to me.

Comment: Cross posted https://mathoverflow.net/questions/285204/category-of-cocommutative-hopf-monoids-in-an-exact-category